# Unable to set placeholder on password input

Tags: users, input-formats

```
function customization_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['account']['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Password');
}
```

I am trying to set placeholder on password field in registration form.

I seted placeholder on username and email, but on password field won't work...

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Wish I'd seen this sooner. You've probably moved on from this problem, but for the benefit of other people seeking an answer to this question: (obviously replace mymodule with the name of your module)

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_element_info_alter ()
*/
function mymodule_element_info_alter (& $type)
{
  if (isset($type['password_confirm']['#process'])) {
    $func = '_mymodule_process_password_confirm';

    $type['password_confirm']['#process'][] = $func;
  }

  return $type;
}

/**
 * Do a bit of processing for the password_confirm element.
 * Original processing happens in expand_password_confirm()
 */
function _mymodule_process_password_confirm ($element)
{
  // Use the element's title, or create a custom title with the t() function.
  $element['pass1']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $element['pass1']['#title'];
  $element['pass2']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $element['pass2']['#title'];

  // Remove these lines if you want to keep the field labels.
  $element['pass1']['#title_display'] = 'none';
  $element['pass2']['#title_display'] = 'none';

  return $element;
}
```

Comment: De nada. Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

turibe solution is true. But you can save #title keys (do not remove), for compatibility with another modules.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_element_info_alter ()
*/
function mymodule_element_info_alter (& $type)
{
  if (isset($type['password_confirm']['#process'])) {
    $func = '_mymodule_process_password_confirm';

    $type['password_confirm']['#process'][] = $func;
  }

  return $type;
}

/**
 * Do a bit of processing for the password_confirm element.
 * Original processing happens in expand_password_confirm()
 */
function _mymodule_process_password_confirm ($element)
{
  $element['pass1']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Password');
  $element['pass2']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Confirm password');

  // Remove these lines if you want to keep the field labels
  // Hide labels for pass fields
  $element['pass1']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
  $element['pass2']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';

  return $element;
}
```