# How do I add a placeholder into the password field?

Tags: users

How do I add a placeholder into the password field using the Logintoboggan module?

Comment: what do you mean by placeholder ? what have you tried? can you give an example?

Comment: html 5 placeholder. Example: $form['account']['conf_mail']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('text')). For password field dont work=(

Comment: .... well sure, every password just shows **** ... sorry i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [This solution][1] for help "Unable to set placeholder on password input" for it.


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/73335/33